# Open upload window by click on MenuItem

Tags: java, menu, upload, vaadin

I want to open the uploadwindow from Upload element by click on MenuItem. Is this possible?
Another idea is to add the upload element in MenuBar, but i think this is impossible, right?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a little javascript could help you:

```
Upload upload = new Upload();
upload.setImmediate(true); // if you want to start upload after selection
upload.addStyleName("my-upload");
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.addItem("Caption", new Command() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem) {
        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
            "document.getElementsByClassName('gwt-FileUpload')[0].click()");
    }
});
addComponent(upload);
addComponent(menuBar);
```

If you want to hide the upload:

```
.v-slot-my-upload {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! To hide the upload I used `.v-upload { display: none;
  visibility: hidden;}`. Your hint doesn't work :(

Comment: The browser considers the JavaScript call as malicious and prevents it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest usecase of MenuBar, MenuItem, Window and Upload, layouting is left for you:

```
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    final Window window = new Window();
    window.setContent(new Upload());
    menuBar.addItem("Caption", new Command()
    {
        @Override
        public void menuSelected(MenuItem selectedItem)
        {
            UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is is possible to open the fileChoose window directly without another window?

Comment: One option is to add Upload directly to layout and stylize it through CSS to look like regular com.ui.vaadin.Button and visually remove default upload button with something like: .gwt-FileUpload {
display: none;
}

Comment: But I can not add a button to menubar :(

Comment: Previus comment was about css hacking Upload to look like MenuBar.MenuItem.